# Stop map from hiding points outside the viewport

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers-3

Is there any way to stop OL3 from only showing the points inside the viewport?  Specifically  when on a polygon for me.  I have polygons being clipped because some points are outside the viewport and I need to zoom out in order to have the entire polygon displayed.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle showing that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - turns out you can make a square shaped polygon with 4 points fine, which I had done.  But to avoid the problem I was having you need to add the first point again as a fifth point.